# How to use laravel RegisterController without standard auth (php artisan make:Auth)

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I thought that `if($this->validator($request->all()))` this would return true or false, but it returns a object every time returns true

```
use RegistersUsers;

protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }


    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'surname' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'age' => 'required|integer|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
        ]);
    }


    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'surname' => $data['surname'],
            'age' => $data['age'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);
    }

    public function register(Request $request){

        if($this->validator($request->all())){
            //create user
            // function after registration
            var_dump('success');
        }else{
            //redirect to ...
            var_dump('fail');
        }
    }
```

Comment: because you arent running the validation you are just asking for a validator ... instead of completely overriding the out of the box setup maybe you should see how it currently is done so you understand what is happening; i know there are traits involved so it is a bit harder to track but the auth related controllers are 'working' examples of using the features of the system

Comment: `Validator::make` only gives you a Validator instance. There are a number of methods you can/must call on that, including: `validate` (throws of invalid, otherwise data is returned), `passes`/`fails` (return simply `true` or `false` without throwing).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a couple of options here:

**Use `validate()`**

```
public function register(Request $request)
{
    $this->validator($request->all())->validate();

    dd('success'); //This won't get called if validation doesn't pass
}
```

Using the above method, Laravel will handle the response for you.

---

or if you want to have more control over the how you handle the validation then you can use the `passes()` method instead:

```
public function register(Request $request)
{
    if ($this->validator($request->all())->passes()) {
        dd('success');
    } else  {
        dd('fail');       
    }
}
```

[Manually creating validators](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#manually-creating-validators)

Comment: how I can do after this condition goes to validator? I tried this redirect()->action('RegisterController@validator'); but don't work